# Understanding buffer/bitrate statistics in Media Player Classic

Tags: buffer, bitrate, media-player-classic, jitter

I understand that the two numbers under bitrate are the average bitrate and the current bitrate of each stream.

But what are the two numbers under buffers? I suppose the second one is the amount of data loaded in memory, but what is the first number? The amount of data decoded?

Also, why are there a jitter and a sync offset?

*(For your reference, here stream 0-6 are video track 1, audio track 1-2 and subtitle track 1-4.)*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The first figure (*680*) is number of frames in buffer. The second one (*4389*) is the amount of memory taken by the frames.

If you are using up to date MPC-HC then the buffer is implemented in LAV Splitter and is limited by two boundaries (in order of their priority):

- frame limit. Default is 350 frames (see [[1](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/blob/master/demuxer/LAVSplitter/PacketQueue.h#L25)]), but is multiplied by `factor` (up to 120 times) if certain conditions are met (see [[2](https://github.com/Nevcairiel/LAVFilters/blob/master/demuxer/LAVSplitter/OutputPin.cpp#L56-L67)])
- byte limit. Default is 256 MB and is rarely reached.