# Increase MPC-HC cache

Tags: video, nas, cache, media-player, media-player-classic

I use Media Player Classic Home Cinema to watch all sorts of videos. I have a NAS where I store my files.

Usually my NAS gets overloaded with requets from my server and other operations on my Main PC, and that makes MPC hang its playback. When that happens I need to pause it and move a few seconds back to watch the lost part.

Is there a way to make MPC load bigger chuncks from files and store them on RAM, so that this cache makes it less vulnerable to network unavailabilites?

I tried to edit LAVSplitter.ax but there's no `69 C5 5E 01 00 00`. https://gist.github.com/vovcacik/5cb46072f6927621acc8 confirms it's outdated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MPC-HC to cache more aggressively](http://superuser.com/questions/842203/how-to-make-mpc-hc-to-cache-more-aggressively)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. `69 C5 5E 01 00 00` isn't found on the file.